# should I test returned object as a whole or separately its properties

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a method that returns validation result object:

```
this.validate = function() {
    //some validation code here

    return {
        result: validation result,
        message: "some message here",
        errors: []
    }
}
```

To test, for example, that validation failed I can do either this way:

```
var validationResult = {
    result: failed,
    message: "some message here",
    errors: []
}

expect(validation.validate(nodes)).toEqual(validationResult);
```

Or this way:

```
expect(validation.validate(nodes).result).toEqual(false);
```

It seems like the second option is how I should test it. Is it correct? Should I then test the entire object, for example, that it has expected structure (fields)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to validate entire object, it is better then matching each property separately and also test should know exact which error should be returned, just matching result boolean it will pass even if there is different kind of error. toEqual uses deep match and matches all properties of objects.

Comment: thanks, but I can also devise separate test for the message property.

Comment: if you have cases when you do not expect all properties of the validationResult filed correctly (for e.g. don't have actual error due to mock used for the part of the functionality) in such cases it will require to test individual property of the validationResult but when there is no specific need I will suggest to validate entire object.

Comment: I have seen many examples where negative test should fail due to not expected error but they were marked successful as only IsSuccess kind of result data validated in unit test.